# Vue - Passing props in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component in which there is a variable which I need to pass to all the child components. Something like:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
   <Child :packet="{item: item, globalvars: globalvars }" />
</div>
```

I am passing this big `globalvars` object to all the instances of `Child` component in my code. Does doing so replicates the `globalvars` in the memory everytime its passed to the `Child` instance? Just wondering how Vue handles this type of situation.

Comment: It is like calling a function several time with the same input. If it is a value type it will be passed by value but wont take much space anyway, otherwise it will be passed by reference  and wont take much space either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments are passed by reference, so data will not be duplicated. However, if any of the children mutate the state of this object, since all components share the same object, this change will also affect sibling components. I assume this is expected though?

However, I personally find `globalvars` a bit vague and there are a number of better designg depending on its use - maybe global plugin, vuex instance or even simple provide/inject?